# Google Cloud Laucher Wordpress Bitnami possible autoscaling?

Tags: wordpress, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I'm currently testing my wordpress site on the google cloud platform (compute engine) .

I have create a Wordpress siti with the Cloud Launcher.
But now...
How to set up a load balancer with auto-scaling?

For load balancing is possible create more equals istanceces?

I'm preparing to set up a start up, so I want to begin with a relatively small resources and then scale out them on-demand.

Best, Alex